# How to apply sum and groupby on a list in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am trying to use `groupby` method on `transactionDay` and take the `sum` of the `transactionAmount`. and print the output.

```
case class Transaction(
  transactionId: String,
  accountId: String,
  transactionDay: Int,
  category: String,
  transactionAmount: Double)
```

I created a list like this:

```
val transactions: List[Transaction] = transactionslines.map { line =>
  val split = line.split(',')
  Transaction(split(0), split(1), split(2).toInt, split(3), split(4).toDouble)
}.toList
```

Can anyone help with using the `groupBy` method.

If you have any documents to share it would be really helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see how to improve your question.

Comment: `transactions.groupBy(_.transctionDay).mapValues(_.map(_.transactionAmount).sum))`

Comment: "if you have any documents to share it would be really helpful." – What's wrong with [the documentation](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#groupBy[K](f:A=>K):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr])?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code should work to get the solution you require

```
val transactions = transactionslines.map( line => line.split(","))
  .map(split => Transaction(split(0), split(1), split(2).toInt, split(3), split(4).toDouble))
transactions.groupBy(_.transactionDay).mapValues(trans => trans.map(amount => amount.transactionAmount).sum).foreach(println)
```